# PHP language based setting

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a MySQL + PHP script where user can configure lanuage based formates

like

```
dateformat: dd.mm.yyyy
delimiter: , 
currency: €
locale: de
```

Is there any standard available for such configurations?

Comment: What do you mean by standard? Do you mean, if there is something already built-in in php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/it/book.intl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean already built-in in php, yes there is a standard available. It works with locales. You can use the `setlocale()` function, to set the current locale, which has an impact on different php functions, like `strftime()`.
Get a closer look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).

**But** be warned. The output is not always what you would expect, because it is not ISO compliant. There has been a long discussion about the locales and their impact on date functions, but in the end they decided to stay POSIX compliant, which is not ISO compliant.